# Dynamically going from a 3D array to a 2D array in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, malloc

If I have a dynamically defined 3D array defined like so :

```
float   ***tmparray;
int     ii, jj;

tmparray = calloc(100, sizeof(tmparray));

for(ii = 0; ii < 100; ii++)
   tmparray[ii] = calloc(100, sizeof(tmparray[ii]));

for(ii = 0; ii < 100; ii++){
   for(jj = 0; jj < 100; jj++){
      tmparray[ii][jj] = calloc(2, sizeof(tmparray[ii][jj]));
   }
}
```

Could I then do something like

```
for(ii = 0; ii < 100; ii++){
   for(jj = 0; jj < 100; jj++){
      free(tmparray[ii][jj]);
   }
}
```

And continue to use it like a regular 2D array? Or is this not allowed?

**EDIT:** This isn't implemented code, this is just out of curiosity. So it isn't "real" code in that sense.

Comment: `float   ***tmparray` is not a 3D array but a pointer-to-pointer-to-pointer. Arrays and pointers in C are quite distinct, but often mixed up.

Comment: Isn't an array just a pointer to it's first location? That's what I was told... In this case, I guess it'd be a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to it's first location, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
tmparray = calloc(100, sizeof(tmparray));
```

is wrong:

1. It doesn't make sense to use `calloc()` on pointers. "All bits zero" is not guaranteed to have a well-defined meaning for pointers.
2. The size is wrong; you're saying you want 100 items the size of the *pointer*, it should be `sizeof *tmparray`.
3. Remember that `sizeof` is not a function, the parentheses are only needed if the argument is a cast expression (like `sizeof (int)`).

Comment: So should it be `tmparray = calloc(100, sizeof(***tmparray));` in this case?

Answer (score 0):

There's a mistake while calloc.

```
tmparray = calloc(100, sizeof(*tmparray));

for(ii = 0; ii < 100; ii++)
   tmparray[ii] = calloc(100, sizeof(*tmparray[ii]));

for(ii = 0; ii < 100; ii++){
   for(jj = 0; jj < 100; jj++){
      tmparray[ii][jj] = calloc(2, sizeof(*tmparray[ii][jj]));
   }
}
```

And back to question simply no, you can't, because

```
sizeof(*tmparray[ii]) == sizeof(float*)
```

while

```
sizeof(*tmparray[ii][jj]) == sizeof(float)
```

P.S. On 32-bit machine it should work but is not a portable way to do it.